# Como puedo leer un texto plano desde una url?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de leer un texto plano (Un String..)desde una url, Por ejemplo: al poner mi url en unnavegador el resultado que estoy esperando es un "string "....intente de esta forma pero no logre a capturar el resultado,  alguien me puede ayudar?
Ahi esta el mi codigo

```
 class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL("www.miUrl.com");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if(code==200){
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                if (in != null) {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        result += line;
                }
                in.close();
            }

            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(InformaCaja.this, + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Usar un Asynctask como lo realizas es lo ideal, solo necesitas unos pequeños cambios, agregué respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `Asynctask` que usas puede funcionar, primero define el permiso para uso de internet en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

y solo que necesitas definir la url de un archivo, por ejemplo puedes usar como prueba este url:

"https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"

Modificando tu código:

```
   class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                String result = "";
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"/*"www.miUrl.com"*/);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                    if(code==200){
                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                        if (in != null) {
                            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                            String line = "";

                            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                                result += line;
                        }
                        in.close();
                    }

                    return result;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                return result;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Toast.makeText(InformaCaja.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
```

Ahora cuando desees llamar la descarga y lectura del archivo, llama tu Asynctask de esta forma:

```
  new GetData().execute();
```

Comment: muchas gracias @Jorgesys me ayudo mucho tu repuesta :)

Comment: Excelente @ApseSony, me da gusto ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

En lo personal me gusta usar la librería [okhttp3](https://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Se me ha hecho más práctico hacer request desde android con ese paquete. Te anexo un ejemplo de como podrías lograr lo que deseas con okhttp3:

```
public static  String getString(String path) {
            URL url;
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            try {
                url = new URL(path);
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .build();
                try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
                    return response.body().string();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return null;
            }
}
```